# Android: How do I notify changes from inside 1 ListAdapter to a second ListAdapter?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 2 ListViews both containing their own data.

When the user clicks on a button inside one of the items in the first `ListView` some data changes occur that the second `ListView` should be notified off. However I can't seem to get this to work. Below the simplified relevant code:

This is the first ListFragment.  Inside the AsyncTask the first custom ListAdapter is set with `setListAdapter()` during `onPostExecute()`.

```
public class FragmentAListSupport extends SherlockListFragment {
    String url = "omitted";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> asynctask = 
            new DownloadFilesTask(this).execute(url);       
    }
}
```

This is the second ListFragment. Inside the AsyncTask the second custom ListAdapter is set with `setListAdapter()` during `onPostExecute()`.

```
public class FragmentBListSupport extends SherlockListFragment {
    String url = "omitted";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> asynctask = 
            new DownloadDataTask(this).execute(url);        
    }
}
```

Inside the custom adapter used by the first ListFragment (A) I have the onButtonPressed handler.

```
  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  //code omitted
  viewHolder.button
    .setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View buttonview) { 
            //code omitted that changes some local data 
            //I need to notify the other ListFragment (B) here that it should update 
        }             
     {    
   }
```

Now for my question...

How do I correctly use notifyDataSetChanged() from inside the first adapter (A) to notify the second adapter (B) that it should update the ListView? I am confused about how I should retrieve the correct reference to the second adapter from inside the first adapter because they are both initialized inside an AsyncTask.

Any help would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do some thing like this:

from one fragment create a method that returns the instance of your adapter:

```
  public customAdapter getDataAdapter()
  {
       return dataAdapter;
  }
```

and in the second fragment get an instance of your first fragment:
and then:

```
firstfragment.getDataAdapter().clear();
firstfragment.getDataAdapter().addAll(allDataSet);
```